# Is there a way to unhide hidden-visibility symbols with GNU binutils?

Tags: c, gcc, visibility, binutils

I'm working on a script to make uClibc usable on an existing glibc-targetted gcc/binutils toolchain, and the one problem I'm left with is that `pthread_cancel` needs to `dlopen` `libgcc_s.so.1`. The version supplied with the host gcc is linked to depend on glibc, so I'm instead using `ld`'s `-u` option to pull in the needed symbols (and their dependencies) from `libgcc_eh.a` to make a replacement `libgcc_s.so.1`:

```
gcc -specs uclibc.specs -Wl,-u,_Unwind_Resume -Wl,-u,__gcc_personality_v0 \
    -Wl,-u,_Unwind_ForcedUnwind -Wl,-u,_Unwind_GetCFA -shared -o libgcc_s.so.1
```

In principle I would be done, but all the symbols in `libgcc_eh.a` have their visibility set to hidden, so in the output `.so` file, they all become local and don't get added to the `.dynsym` symbol table.

I'm looking for a way to use binutils (perhaps `objcopy`? or a linker script?) on either the `.so` file or the original `.o` files in `libgcc_eh.a` to un-hide these symbols. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`objcopy` doesn't seem to have this feature, but you can do it with the [ELFkickers `rebind` tool](https://github.com/BR903/ELFkickers/tree/master/rebind):

```
rebind --visibility default file.o SYMBOLS...
```

This must be done on the original .o files. If you try to do it on the .so it'll be too late, because the hidden symbols will have been omitted from the `.dynsym` section.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to use `--globalize-symbol` in objcopy.

e.g.

```
$ nm /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3/libgcc_eh.a | grep emutls_alloc

00000000 t emutls_alloc
$ objcopy  --globalize-symbol=emutls_alloc /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3/libgcc_eh.a /tmp/libgcc_eh.a
$ nm /tmp/libgcc_eh.a |grep emutls_alloc
00000000 T emutls_alloc
```

You can provide --globalize-symbol several times to objcopy, but you'll need to  explicitly mention the full symbol name of all the symbols you want to globalize.

<s>Though I'm not sure what kind of breakage could occur turning libgcc_eh.a into a shared object, as libgcc_eh.a is presumably compiled without -fpic/-fPIC.</s>  Turns out libgcc_eh.a is compiled as position independent code.

Comment: Presumably the object files in `libgcc_eh.a` should be usable in PIC shared libraries or PIE executables, since it gets pulled into them when shared `libgcc_s.so` is not being used, but I may be mistaken. In any case it will work at least on i386 where textrels are allowed.

Comment: Just saw your edit. Leaving my comment because I think it explains *why* the code is compiled as PIC.

Comment: Unfortunately `--globalize-symbol` only changes the GLOBAL/LOCAL state. As far as I can see, objcopy has no options to change the DEFAULT/HIDDEN state.