# Changing visibility of hidden symbols on OS X

Tags: c++, c, macos, shared-libraries, visibility

I'm using a 3rd party static library in my application (which means I can't recompile it).
This library was built using `-stdlib=libstdc++` i.e. for compatibility with macOS versions < 10.9: since this version, `stdlib=libc++` by default.
But this means all my application code has to be built with `-stdlib=libstdc++`, which prevents me to use some C++11 features.

So I tried to convert this static library to a shared library, but then the symbols were not visible.
Indeed, using nm I can see they are marked `t` instead of `T` which seems to be OK when linking statically, but is not when linking dynamically.

I wanted to change the visibility of the symbols I need to global.
I'm not sure how I can achieve it on macOS, since `objcopy` is not available here (it as an option called`--globalize-symbol` which seems to do what I want, according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377608/is-there-a-way-to-unhide-hidden-visibility-symbols-with-gnu-binutils))

Comment: `objcopy` is part of `binutils` which [AFAICT] _is_ available for macOS. Either from source or: http://macappstore.org/binutils/ A web search on "binutils mac OS" will produce other links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this using only ld.

`ld -r lib.a -o new_lib.a -alias _old_function_name _new_function_name`

Symbols exported this way are marked as global.
It it nos possible to reuse the same name in one call, but it is when doing this twice i.e. _function(t) -> function(T) -> _function(T)

Then I just built my shared library using something like:
`g++ -fpic -shared -Wl,-force_load new_lib.a -stdlib=libstdc++  -o lib.dylib`

The only thing that bothers me is that I didn't find how to remove the old symbols when creating the new, global ones, but this doesn't seem to create any issue.